# store struct of info in single linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to store a struct of person info into a single linked list and perform some operations on it

my struct infor is

```
struct Person {
    char name[MAX];
    char id[MAX];
};
```

And my single linked list is defined using struct like

```
struct Node {
    struct Person* pPerson;
    struct Node* pNext;
};
```

My idea is to define a `Person` struct by getting input from user

```
struct Person* newPerson() {
    Person* pPerson = NULL;
    pPerson = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("name: "); scanf("%s", pPerson->name);
    printf("id: "); scanf("%s", pPerson->id);
    
    return pPerson;
}
```

This is `initNode` funciton to for newly created node

```
struct Node* newNode(Person* pNewPerson) {
    Node* pPeople = NULL;
    pPeople = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    pPeople->pPerson = pNewPerson;
    return pPeople;
}
```

And this is my `insert` function that store struct Person in list

```
void insert(Node* pHead, Person* pNewPerson) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    while (pCurrent != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    
    pCurrent = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    pCurrent->pNext->pPerson = pNewPerson;
    pCurrent->pNext = NULL;
}
```

Finally is the `display` function

```
void display(Node* pHead) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    int index = 1;
    
    while (pCurrent != NULL) {
        printf("Person %d\n", index);
        printf("name: %s\n", pCurrent->pPerson->name);
        printf("id: %s\n", pCurrent->pPerson->id);
        index += 1;
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
}
```

and I just test but it seems like wrong somewhere in my code

```
    Node* pNode = NULL;
    Person* pPerson = NULL;
    pPerson = newPerson();
    pNode = newNode(pPerson);
    insert(pNode, pPerson);
    display(pNode);
```

when I input values are got but the output is `segmentation default core dump`.
I'm new to pointer I just followed the logic to assign the pointer where it needed to be.

Could someone correct me?

`EDIT`: problems solved

```
struct Person* newPerson() {
    Person* pPerson = NULL;
    pPerson = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    printf("name: "); scanf("%s", pPerson->name);
    printf("id: "); scanf("%s", pPerson->id);
    
    return pPerson;
}

struct Node* newNode(Person* pNewPerson) {
    Node* pPeople = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    pPeople->pPerson = pNewPerson;
    pPeople->pNext = NULL;
    return pPeople;
}
```

```
void insert(Node* pHead, Person* pNewPerson) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    if (pCurrent == NULL)
    {
        return pNewNode;
    }
    while (pCurrent-> pNext != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    pCurrent->pNext = pNewNode;
}

void display(Node* pHead) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    int index = 1;
    
    while (pCurrent != NULL) {
        printf("Person %d\n", index);
        printf("name: %s\n", pCurrent->pPerson->name);
        printf("id: %s\n", pCurrent->pPerson->id);
        index += 1;
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: instead of having structs with strings cranked to `MAX`, use allocations sized exactly as needed, as in `char*` properties.

Comment: Tip: Don't bother with `X* x = NULL; x = (X*) malloc(sizeof(X))` as two steps, just simplify it to `X* x = malloc(sizeof(X))`. No cast required. No pre-NULL.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: See last update of my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67721142/4386427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` function is wrong for several reasons.

The short answer is to do:

```
Node* insert(Node* pHead, Node* pNewNode) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    if (pCurrent == NULL)
    {
        return pNewNode;
    }
    while (pCurrent->next != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    pCurrent->pNext = pNewNode;
    return pHead;
}
```

and call it like:

```
Node* pHead = NULL;
Person* pPerson = newPerson();
Node* pNewNode = newNode(pPerson);
pHead = insert(pHead, pNewNode);
```

and also insert `pPeople->pNext = NULL;` in the `newNode` function.

**EXPLANATION:**

Start here:

```
void insert(Node* pHead, Person* pNewPerson) {
```

Why take `pNewPerson` as argument? You already inserted the new person into a node using the `newNode` function. So instead do:

```
void insert(Node* pHead, Node* pNewNode) {
    ...
}
```

and call it like:

```
Node* pHead = NULL;
Person* pPerson = newPerson();
Node* pNewNode = newNode(pPerson);
insert(pHead, pNewNode);
```

This part:

```
while (pCurrent != NULL) {
    pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
}
```

brings you past the last element so there is no way you can add the new element to the last element. Your code should be:

```
void insert(Node* pHead, Node* pNewNode) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    if (pCurrent == NULL)
    {
        ..se later..
    }
    while (pCurrent->next != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    // Now pCurrent points to the last element
```

You code to insert the element is also wrong - see comments

```
pCurrent = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));  // Why malloc - you did that in newNode-function
pCurrent->pNext->pPerson = pNewPerson;   // Why - you did that in newNode-function
pCurrent->pNext = NULL;
```

Most of the code isn't needed. Just do:

```
void insert(Node* pHead, Node* pNewNode) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    if (pCurrent == NULL)
    {
        ..se later..
    }
    while (pCurrent->next != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    pCurrent->pNext = pNewNode;
}
```

Now what if `pHead` is NULL ? In that case you need to update `pHead` to be the new node. To do that you need to change the function again. One way is:

```
Node* insert(Node* pHead, Node* pNewNode) {
    Node* pCurrent = pHead;
    if (pCurrent == NULL)
    {
        return pNewNode;
    }
    while (pCurrent->next != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
    pCurrent->pNext = pNewNode;
    return pHead;
}
```

and call it like:

```
Node* pHead = NULL;
Person* pPerson = newPerson();
Node* pNewNode = newNode(pPerson);
pHead = insert(pHead, pNewNode);
```

Comment: Your explanation is very clear! Thank you for figuring out something that I still don't realize!

Answer (score 0):

In your `insert` function, you access `pCurrent->pNext`, however, `pNext` is not initialized by `newNode`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change while loop of insert function like the following way.

```
   while (pCurrent != NULL && pCurrent->pNext != NULL) {
        pCurrent = pCurrent->pNext;
    }
```

the reason you get segmentation fault error is that you set null value to pCurrent pointer when pCurrent->pNext is Null. after that, you try dereferencing null pointer in the following code;

```
pCurrent->pNext = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

You can also check @4386427 answer and explanation I didnt review the other part of your code but you get a segmentation error for the reason that I specified above.